# How to take in two different values in android?

Tags: android, user-input

basically what I've tried, is to create a XML with two input types decimal. Input A and Input B, and when I click add, these values will get passed onto a class method, and that method will do so and so.

The problem I have is that I have no way of passing the value from an XML file to a java file (I think)

I spent like an hour doing the XML thing only to find out I can't do it.

Can you possibly guide me as to how I might go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
EditText mEditText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number1i); 
String val1 = mEditText1.getText().toString();
EditText mEditText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number2i); 
String val2 = mEditText2.getText().toString();
```

Comment: I removed the. after the findViewById and there is no error. The problem I have now is, I want to pass the values onto a method that takes parameters method(double,double).

Comment: double dVal1 = Double.parseDouble(val1);
double dVal2 = Double.parseDouble(val2);

Comment: Hi, sorry if I'm being annoying but I'm getting a nullPointerException at String val1 = mEditText1.getText().toString(); / Any idea what it could be?

Comment: Check whether you have a EditText in the layout and its id is number1i

Comment: I can confirm that's correct, but the problem is after running the app. When I hit the button, the app crashes. Thank you for your help

Comment: did you check whether mEditText1 is not null? also check mEditText1.getText()

Comment: I just uploaded my XML file. I don't think the mEditText1 is null. Maybe the number i write in the edit text (in the app) never gets assigned to the number1i for instance?

Comment: Clean and build the app again. I think mEditText1 is null. mEditText1.getText() cannot be null. Even if you leave it blank.

Answer (score 1):

Your XML contains two editText and one button?

in your java file you should do:

```
EditText e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.e1);
```

> EditText e2= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.e2);

and in xml set onClick attribute on button (example onClick="onClick")
in code:

```
public void onClick(View v){
```

> e1.getText.toString(); e2.getText.toString(); //save it to string and
>   you have what you want}

Comment: EditText e1 = (Button)  how could it cast?

Comment: I have updated my XML if that helps. I'm getting a findViewById cannot be resolved error

Comment: R.id.e1 is a reference to your editText id in xml did you add id to widgets in xml?

Comment: Use R.id.number1i and R.id.number2i instead

Comment: Do you mean the id of the buttons in my XML that I've added now? If so, how can I add id to widgets?

Comment: I did harikris: EditText e1 = (EditText)findViewById.(R.id.number1i); 
  EditText e2 = (EditText)findViewById.(R.id.number2i);

Comment: <EditText
               
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/login_edit_text_login" <- id of widget
 
                />

Comment: I deleted the . after findViewById and there is no error now.

Comment: Yeah it is fine now. Thanks a-lot!